# シェルスクリプトで各ディレクトリ名の頭文字を一文字消すには

Tags: sh, shellscript

UNIX環境でシェルスクリプトを使って，以下のようにディレクトリ名を一括で変更するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

変更前:

- a12456
- b12459
- e12461
- u12467

変更後:

- 12456
- 12459
- 12461
- 12467

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bash でよければ、

```
$ for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f:1}"; done
```

です。`for f in *` としていますので、カレントディレクトリにある `.` で始まるファイル以外の全てのファイルが対象になりますのでご注意下さい。

Answer (score 3):

提示例の行頭 - は真のファイル名にはあるのでしょうか、それとも列挙の意図でつけた文字で実際には無し？
先頭の１文字を削除するのであれば

```
for i in *; do if [ -d $i ]; then mv -f $i `echo $i | sed -e s/^.//`; fi; done
```

とか。
３文字目を削除するならそのように直すと良いです。

ディレクトリ `abcd` と `bcd` が両方あるときどうなるべきかは事前に考察が必要っす。

Answer (score 2):

外部コマンドは不要です。bash, ksh, zsh 依存の `${var:offset}` なしでも POSIX sh の構文だけで実現可能です。

```
$ for d in [a-z]*; do [ -d "$d" ] && mv -- "$d" "${d#?}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

大喜利みたいですが こういうのも思いつきました。
利点は名前を展開しないのでディレクトリがたくさん有ってもエラーになりません。

```
$ ls -1 | sed 's/^.\(.*\)$/mv \0 \1/' | sh
```